# Use generics to indicate return type of child method

Tags: python, generics

I have a mixin that is used by several child classes and would like to make sure PyCharm and `mypy` can infer that the return type of the `add_value` method on a child object is the type of the child class, not the type of the mixin. Any ideas how to do this with Generics? Currently PyCharm indicates that the return type of calling `add_value` from an instance of `MyMixinUser` is `MyMixin`, not `MyMixinUser`

```
T = TypeVar('T', bounds='MyMixin')


class MyMixin(Generic[T]):

    value: int

    def add_value(self: T, value) -> T:

        return type(self)(self.value + value)


class MyMixinUser(
    MyMixin,
    object
):

    def __init__(self, value: int):

        self.value = value
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to return the type from add_Value?

Comment: All the subclasses that use the mixin have several methods that return a new instance of themselves with some wrapped data. Some are inherited from mixins, others belong to the subclasses. I want to chain these methods together and currently when I do this I lose the type of the original subclass as soon as I call an inherited method.

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? For starters, you don't have to make `MyMixin` generic, just fix `bounds=` to `bound=` (I assume this is a typo) and that is correctly annotated without having to inherit from `Generic[T]`. As you state, mypy correctly infers `MyMixinUser(1).add_value(1)` as being of the type `MyMixinUser`. Are you asking "why doesn't PyCharm?"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga making those changes worked, thank you.